# is that ok to have @Autowire or @Inject in @Configuration class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc-test

Spring 5, Java 8
I have multiple configuration files, one of the configuration file has @Autowire dependency. it does not complain on run time and works fine but intellij warns can't find those beans.

wondering if thats ok to have `@Autowire` or `@Inject` in configuration class.

why i have it is b/c its my websocket configuration and my handlers need dependencies.

Comment: you mean like this? in general it's ok: https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch04s02.html but maybe you're doing something different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's OK.

`@Configuration` indicates that a class declares `@Bean`s which might require dependencies. `@Configuration` itself is meta-annotated with `@Component` and "therefore may also take advantage of `@Autowired`/`@Inject` like any regular `@Component`".

I would recommend that you pass dependencies as method parameters rather than inject them into fields. It keeps the configuration class clear and emphasises the required dependencies for each `@Bean` method.

I prefer

```
class C {
    @Bean
    public A a(B b) { new A(b); }
}
```

to

```
class C {
    private final B b;        

    @Bean
    public A a() { new A(b); }
}
```